# Dynamic array allocation - valgrind conditional jump

Tags: c, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to read a line from stdin in C and at the same time dynamically allocate memory for the string using the code snippet from below. The problem is that when I run this code, calling something like `strlen(msg)` results in an `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` in valgrinds output.

I don't understand how to get past this problem because I can't properly initialize it if I am dynamically allocating it. I've spent a really long time on this now and can't seem to figure it out... any help would be much appreciated.

```
char* msg = NULL;
int c;

// set initial size for dynamic allocation
msg = malloc(sizeof(char)*10+1);

int idx = 0;
char* temp = NULL;
size_t size = 10;
while (1){
    c = getchar();
    if(c == EOF || c == '\n'){
        break;
    }else if(!isalpha(c)){
        free(msg);
        exit(100);
    }

    // dynamically reallocate memory if input too large
    if(size <= idx){
        size += size;
        temp = realloc(msg, size);
        msg = temp;
    }
    msg[idx++] = (char)c;
    
}
printf("%ld", strlen(msg));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never *terminate* the string you create in `msg`.

After the loop (but before you use `msg` as a null-terminated string with e.g. `strlen(msg)`) add the terminator:

```
msg[idx] = '\0';
```

---

There's another problem though, which might crop up unexpectedly: When you reallocate the memory you don't add space for the terminator.

Use-case for this problem: You enter a string with exactly `20` characters.

You will then have reallocated once, making the size exactly `20` bytes (characters). The last character will be put at index `19`, then `idx` is increased to `20` (which is out of bounds). Next iteration of the loop you detect the newline, and break out, and will then set the terminator on the **21:st** character in your 20-character array.

Add `1` to the size when calling `realloc` to solve this:

```
temp = realloc(msg, size + 1);
```

Comment: @Shaxey Updated my answer with details about another problem.